# Deserialize two different types into the same one

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

I have a simple structure that contains a resources field. I would like my resources to always be [Url](https://docs.rs/url/1.6.0/url/struct.Url.html)s.
In the actual file that I am trying to deserialize, resources can either be URLs or [Path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html).

Here is my structure:

```rust
pub struct Myfile {
    pub resources: Vec<Resource>,
}

pub type Resource = Url;
```

I would like to use serde to:

1. Try to deserialize each `Resource` using the implementation from the url crate.
2. If it fails, try to deserialize each one of them into a Path and then use [`url::from_*_path()`](https://docs.rs/url/1.6.0/url/struct.Url.html#method.from_file_path) to get a Url.

I am trying to adapt the [string or map](https://serde.rs/string-or-struct.html),[map](https://serde.rs/deserialize-map.html) and [structure](https://serde.rs/deserialize-struct.html) examples but I am struggling to understand where to even start.

Since my end result will by a Url, the examples seem to show that I should be implementing Deserialize for Url. But I still need to current implementation. My `Resource` is an alias so I can't implement Deserialize for it.

Is there any simple way to deserialize both Paths and Urls into Urls?

PS: I will probably go for the answer proposed but after reading through [this post](https://damad.be/joost/blog/rust-serde-deserialization-of-an-enum-variant.html), I tried the following which seems to work too:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Resource(Url);


impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Resource {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
        where D: Deserializer<'de>
    {
        let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;

        if let path = Path::new(&s) {
            if path.is_file() {
                Ok(Resource(Url::from_file_path(path).unwrap()))
            } else {
                Ok(Resource(Url::from_directory_path(path).unwrap()))
            }
        } else {
            Url::deserialize(s.into_deserializer()).map(|x| Resource(x))
        }
    }
}
```

But is less convenient to work with than regular Urls.

Comment: The simplest would probably to use `deserialize_with`, try to deserialize as a `Url`, then try to deserialize as a `Path` and convert that to a resource. However since you're deserializing to a `Vec<T>` rather than a `T`, you need a wrapper type so you can implement `Deserialize` and do that internally.

Comment: @Masklinn I've [tried](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab22af4f73e238942eb698a98467286a) this and ran into a problem: I can't try to deserialize as Url first, because that consumes the deserialzer, and then it's gone… Anyway, I think there's an easier way.

Comment: I found https://damad.be/joost/blog/rust-serde-deserialization-of-an-enum-variant.html and I am trying to see if the solution at the end could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key to doing this with reasonable effort is to realize that `serde::Deserialize` for `Url` is also just [cooking with water](https://github.com/servo/rust-url/blob/48fcbe1c543a8350a74b226c17c1ec06c6e19a68/url/src/lib.rs#L2645), i.e. just expecting a string and calling `Url::parse` on it.

So it's time to deploy my favourite serde trick: deserialize to a struct that serde can handle easily:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct MyfileDeserialize {
    pub resources: Vec<String>,
}
```

Tell serde that it should get the struct you finally want from that easily handlable struct:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(try_from = "MyfileDeserialize")]
pub struct Myfile {
    pub resources: Vec<Resource>,
}
```

Finally, you just need to define how to turn `MyfileDeserialize` into `Myfile`.

```
impl TryFrom<MyfileDeserialize> for Myfile {
    type Error = &'static str; // TODO: replace with anyhow or a proper error type
    fn try_from(t: MyfileDeserialize) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        Ok(Self {
            resources: t
                .resources
                .into_iter()
                .map(|url| {
                    if let Ok(url) = Url::parse(&url) {
                        return Ok(url);
                    };
                    if let Ok(url) = Url::from_file_path(url) {
                        return Ok(url);
                    };
                    // try more from_*_path here.
                    Err("Can't as url or path")
                })
                .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?,
        })
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab22af4f73e238942eb698a98467286a)

---

Edit regarding your PS:

If you are willing to mess around with manually implementing deserializer traits and functions, I suppose you do have the option of completely getting rid of any wrapper structs or mediating `TryFrom` types: add a [`#[serde(deserialize_with = …)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with) to your `resources`, and in there, first do a `<Vec<String>>::deserialize(de)?`, and then turn that into a `Vec<Url>` as usual.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fada7526495b5d358b348fb9de2f54ee)

Comment: I am going with this. I tried it and it works. An added benefit is that I can take care of other annoying fields in `MyFile`, all at once.